# On Stark's conjecture for imaginary quadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, reference-request

In the famous paper "L-Functions at s = 1. IV. First Derivatives at s = 0" of Stark from 1980, it is shown that in the case of an imaginary quadratic field $K$ certain numbers of the form $$exp(-\frac{d}{ds}\zeta_\mathfrak c(s)|_{s=0}),$$ so called Stark units, provide abelian extensions of $K$.
In other words the above number is the leading coefficient in the Taylor expansion (around zero) of the partial zeta function $\zeta _{\mathfrak c}(s)$ which occurs in the decomposition of an Artin L-series $L(\chi,s) = \Sigma _\mathfrak c \chi(\mathfrak c) \zeta _\mathfrak c (s)$ associated with a character $\chi$ of Gal(L/ K) where $L/K$ is abelian. Stark proved this by showing that $\frac{d}{ds} \zeta _\mathfrak c (s)| _{s=0} $ is equal to the logarithm (of the norm) of a certain modular function at a CM point. Thanks to the theory of Complex Multiplication we know that these values are indeed abelian over $K$.

Now, I would like to know if there are proofs of this beautiful theorem "avoiding" the theory of CM. It should be possible to use only an elliptic curve with complex multiplication by $K$ and its special functions like the Weierstrass' $\mathfrak p$-function or $\theta$-functions.

If there is proof somewhere (in the literature) written in the language of Beilinson's framework, I would be especially delighted.

(A side question: What is known about Stark units in the case of CM fields? I would guess that their should be partial results corresponding to the partial solution of Hilbert's 12th in case of CM fields. Is there some reference?)

Comment: I don't know enough to go below and give a real "answer".  But I don't know of anyone revisiting the case of K imaginary quadratic.  The reason is that most people have been trying to prove the conjectures and their generalizations over arbitrary base fields.  For instance, see the spectacular recent work by Popescu and Greither.  Even if someone were to revisit the case of K imaginary quadratic to do things using special functions, I would imagine that they would attack at least the Rubin-Stark conjectures (Rubin K., A Stark Conjecture "over Z" for abelian L-functions with multiple zeros).  

Comment: Beyond this, most work has been on proving the Equivariant Tamagawa Number Conjecture for Dirichlet Motives, of which the Rubin-Stark conjecture is a consequence.  Popescu and Greither discuss this.  You would probably also like the Proceedings from the PCMI conference on special values of L-functions from the 2009 PCMI when the become available.

Comment: Dear Barry, thank you very much for your comments! I will have a look at the references you suggest. Is there a "short" answer to the question why people believe the ETNC for let's say real quadratic fields might be in reach? Is there a geometric "gadget" that is used like elliptic curves or the modular curve in the case of imaginary quadratic fields? 